# attempted relative import beyond top-level package python

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

How do I import a class from a lower-level directory in python?

I've been reading about how I should add `__init__.py`to my folders (or is this only in python2?) or how I should use `from __future__.py import absolute_import`, but none of those work.

With the code below I get: **ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package**

Also I've tried importing like `from .folder2.file2 import Class2`, which gives the error: **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.folder2'; '__main__' is not a package**

[Directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S36jW.png)

main.py

```
from folder1.file1 import Class1
if __name__ == "__main__":
    Class1()
```

file1.py

```
from ..folder2.file2 import Class2
class Class1:
    def __init__(self):
        print("Foo")
        Class2()
```

file2.py

```
class Class2:
    def __init__(self):
        print("Bar")
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you'll need to add an `__init__.py` to all of the folders Python needs to look through (regardless of your python version), i.e. if you have a structure like this:

```
importing
- folder1
-- file1.py
- folder2
--file2.py
- main.py
```

you'll want it to end up looking something like this:

```
importing
- __init__.py
- folder1
-- __init__.py
-- file1.py
- folder2
-- __init__.py
--file2.py
- main.py
```

i.e. you need an `__init__.py` in `folder1`, `folder2`, *and* `importing`

Comment: After adding those I still get the same error about attempted relative import beyond top-level packages. Are the __init__.py files supposed to be empty?

Comment: Ok got it working, had to remove the two dots from the import statement. Thanks so much.